# Is it acceptable to navigate to the non-home page in a mobile app at startup

Tags: mobile, user-experience

I'm working on a restaurant management mobile application and I have got a requirement to implement a feature where if a user opens the app while there is an incoming order, the app will automatically navigate to the incoming order page instead of the home page (which is ~2 clicks away from the incoming order page). Is this an acceptable practice to automatically navigate to a page that's not the home page at the app startup? I'm worried for example that the user will be confused seeing different pages each time they open the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am doint that with below code

```
if let VC = UIApplication.topViewController1(){
   let nextVC = AppStoryboard.StoryBoardName.viewController(viewControllerClass: OrderVC.self)
   VC.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
}
```

You need to handle back click.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should distinguish between the app going to background and the user closing the app and relaunching it. In the first case, normally the app is kept on the view where it was. In the second case, as you say, most apps show the homepage instead of jumping to another page.

That being said, for your particular scenario, I can easily imagine that the restaurant employees want to process an incoming order as soon as possible, and I believe that’s the reason behind that requirement.

I think the relevant UX pattern here is that of a push [notification](https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/patterns/notification-pattern/). When there’s an incoming order, the device receives a push notification. When the person taps on that notification, she’s taken to the incoming order page for that order.

Whether or not to show the incoming order page when the user launches the app (or returns from background), to me it depends on the number of orders. If lots of orders are received in a short amount of time, it could end up being confusing. It would be much better to take the user to a page with a list of incoming orders, the new ones being highlighted in bold font with a red icon, for example.

If you're worried about breaking external consistency, i.e. it's unusual to navigate to a non-home page on startup, external consistency can be broken, if it's absolutely necessary, according to [Jakob's Nielsen usability heuristic on consistency and standards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ibndy9KLOSQ).

If you don't want to navigate to the incoming orders page on startup, an alternative would be to add on the homepage a clear indication that there are orders in progress, such as a badge count or a banner with some kind of easily accessible button or link to go to the incoming orders list page.